# Replacing "Please provide password to perform action" pattern under OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

In my application, I request the user provide their password for certain actions. This attempts to ensure the person performing the action is reconfirmed as the current user.

However, with OAuth I am not sure how to, or if it is possible, to get the authentication provider to reconfirm the user. There doesn't seem to be a consistent way to get a provider to require the user to reauthenticate.

Other than modifying my OAuth authentication flow for each provider, is there a way to require a user to reauthenticate?

Or, in the context of OAuth, is there a better way to replace this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this based on scopes, where the app initially redirects like this:

```
https://login.example.com?client_id=xxx&scope=openid ...
```

To perform high privilege operations the app gets an access token with a high privilege scope. You can force re-entry of the password using the OpenID Connect `prompt=login` parameter. Depending on the type of data involved, you can also inform the user in a consent screen:

```
https://login.example.com?client_id=xxx&scope=openid payment&prompt=login
```

The Authorization Server could also be configured to require multi factor authentication for high privilege scopes. You could then avoid re-entry of a password via `prompt=none` and prompt only for a second factor.

After re-authentication, a high privilege access token is returned to the app and sent to an API. The API only allows these operations when there is a high privilege scope.